# How to calculate a moving average from last 4 days in databricks with SQL

Tags: sql, analytics, databricks

I am trying to calculate a moving average from the last four days (Business demanda).

The stack is currently databricks and I ams trying to keep it to SQL language. I`ve found somw way to do with py_spark and pands bus I need to to in SQL.

The documentantio in [Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-window-functions.html) didn`t help a lot so I was wondering if anyone has a clue?

Comment: you have to provide data and shoe us your desired output

Comment: Quick tip, Databricks SQL and MySQL syntax are almost the same. If you find any example using MySQL then  try the same.